# Angular 2 Lazy loading and Interceptors together

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, interceptor

I have a problem i using Interceptors with lazy loading the modules. it is showing the error of "Cannot find the module". So basically I think lazy loading routes are not working with interceptors. When I try Interceptors and routing separately, both works.
I read somewhere that lazy loading share a different Dependency Injection Tree, hence the conflicts arises.
Here is the code for the the interceptors.

```
    import {
    Http,
    Request,
    RequestOptionsArgs,
    Response,
    XHRBackend,
    RequestOptions,
    ConnectionBackend,
    Headers
} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';

export class HttpService extends Http {

    constructor(backend : ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions : RequestOptions, private _router: Router) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url : string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable < Response > {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
    }

    get(url : string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable < Response > {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, options));
    }

    post(url : string, body : string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable < Response > {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    put(url : string, body : string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable < Response > {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    delete(url : string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable < Response > {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : RequestOptionsArgs {
        if(options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        options
            .headers
            .append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return options;
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable < Response >) : Observable < Response > {
        return observable.catch((err:any, source:any) => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this._router.navigate(['/loginhiring-calendar']);
                return new EmptyObservable();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });

    }}
```

And Routing code is a lazy loading routing

Comment: The routing code?

Comment: Sorry for that, updated with the routing code

Comment: You can use the interceptor from HttpClientModule now.